# Durant et pendant : sens différent ? (Littré)

Tags: usage, adverbes, synonymes

[Littré écrit :](http://alendar.google.com/calendar/b/1/r/week/2019/9/26?hl=fr&rst=1&es=1&sf=true&response_updated=1)

> DURANT, PENDANT. Durant, participe du verbe durer pris pour préposition, garde sa signification primitive ; mais pendant n'implique point cette signification. Ainsi l'on dira : durant la campagne, les ennemis se sont tenus enfermés dans leurs places ; et c'est pendant cette campagne que s'est livrée la bataille dont vous parlez.

Cette distinction entre durant (durée continue) et pendant (laps de temps) est-elle toujours respectée ? Ou est-ce une distinction de la langue soignée ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans la 10<sup>e</sup> édition du *Bon Usage* (1975), Grevisse notait cette distinction en ajoutant qu'« on [ne pouvait donner à celle-ci] un caractère absolu ».

Plus de 40 ans plus tard [TermiumPlus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=97EJVJsHgxT8.html) dit que ces deux prépositions « sont aujourd’hui considérées » comme des synonymes et signale comme « intéressante » la nuance qui existait « autrefois » entre les deux mots.

Le linguiste [Bernard Cerquiglini](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cerquiglini) dans [le podcast](https://www.tv5mondeplus.com/toutes-les-videos/documentaire/merci-professeur--pendant-et-durant) qu'il consacra à ces deux prépositions en 2014 se montrait plus nuancé :

> Les propositions « pendant » et  « durant » semblent synonymes. Il est vrai que bien des choses les rapprochent. Elles proviennent toutes deux de verbes, « pendre » et « durer » au participe présent. Elles doivent toutes deux leur emploi prépositionnel à un usage juridique. [...] Notons toutefois que « pendant » paraît davantage grammaticalisé, c'est-à-dire figé. Une preuve, comme locution conjonctive, « pendant que » est parfaitement courant, signe de sa grammaticalisation avancée. En revanche, « durant que », (*durant que j'hésitais, elle me parla*) me semble très littéraire pour ne pas dire fort affecté, sauf le respect que je dois, bien sûr, aux écrivains qui l'emploient.

Il ne dit pas que l'un ou l'autre (*pendant* ou *durant*) serait plus littéraire/soignée, il se réfère uniquement à la locution *durant que*.

Personnellement il me semble que dans le langage courant la distinction n'est plus faite et je soupçonne qu'elle est ignorée de beaucoup parmi les jeunes générations.

Comment: Super ! Je te remercie !

Comment: Je ne pensais voir un natif écrire : "la distinction n'est plus faite" au lieu de "on ne fait plus la distinction" :-)!

Comment: @Dimitris L'emploi du passif est volontaire, et s'articule avec le passif de la proposition suivante.  Par ailleurs le « on » de ma première phrase est celui de Grevisse, j'aurais dû mettre des guillemets, je rectifie.

Answer (score 0):

« Pendant » est beaucoup plus utilisé dans la langue écrite et dans la langue parlé on n'utilise presque pas « durant », ce qui ne signifie pas que l'on ne peut pas l'utiliser, sauf dans la locution « durant que » comme celle-ci, déjà dans la langue soutenue est d'usage vieilli (TLFi).

[la](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durant+la%2Cpendant+la&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurant%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20la%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdurant%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20la%3B%2Cc0),
[le](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durant+le%2C+pendant+le&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurant%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20le%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdurant%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20le%3B%2Cc0),
[les](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pendant+les%2Cdurant+les&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpendant%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdurant%20les%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpendant%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdurant%20les%3B%2Cc0),
[une](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durant+une%2Cpendant+une&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurant%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20une%3B%2Cc0),
[un](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durant+un%2C+pendant+un&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurant%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20un%3B%2Cc0),
[des](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durant+des%2Cpendant+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurant%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdurant%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpendant%20des%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: J' utilise volontairement durant. Désormais j'utiliserai plutôt pendant:-)! Merci.